# Help understanding a comment about isomorphisms of two direct sums.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I've recently noticed a few different posts asking about this problem [Isomorphism of two direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122414/isomorphism-of-two-direct-sums), all using the CRT. I think I understand it this way. What caught my eye is in the above link a user gives this hint:

> The Bezout identity $\rm\: ad+bc\:\! =\:\! g\:$ yields the following [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) reduction
>   $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 & \!\!\!0 |& \!\!\!a & \!\!\!0\\ 0 &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!0 & \!\!\!b\end{array}\right]$
>   $\sim$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 & \!\!\!1 |& \!\!\!a & \!\!\!b\\ 0 &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!0 & \!\!\!b\end{array}\right]$
>   $\sim$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 & \!\!\!1 |& \!\!\!a & \!\!\!b\\ 0 &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!0 & \!\!\!b\end{array}\right]$ 
>   $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 & \!\!\!0 |& \rm d &\rm \!\!\!\smash{-\!b/g}\\ 0 &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!\rm c &\rm a/g\end{array}\right]
> $=
>   $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 & \!\!\!1 |& \!\!\!g & \!\!\!0\\ 0 &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!bc & \!\!\!ab/g\end{array}\right]$ = $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\rm 1 + bc/g & \!\!\!1 |& \!\!\!gcd(a,b) & \!\!\!0\\ bc/g &\rm \!\!\!1| & \!\!\!0 & \!\!\!lcm(a,b)\end{array}\right]$

The OP became impatient which led the hint giver to not elaborate. To me this seems like a solution. I'm having trouble seeing why it is just a hint.
Can anyone let me know what more I would need to correctly justify the isomorphism?

EDIT: **Left Identity matrix not in orginal comment**. Is adjoining the other matrix more useful?

Comment: To find an explicit isomorphism I think you still need to calculate the row/column transformation matrices. Note also that when $x \neq 0$ divides $y$ in a domain, the notation $y/x$ makes sense, even though $x$ might be a nonunit. If $y = qx = q'x$, then $q = q'$ by cancellation.

Comment: @spin When you say transformation matrix do you mean like what I have done in the edit above?

Comment: @spin Maybe you want to expand your comment to an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).