# Prove that $\operatorname { gcd } ( M , N ) \times \operatorname { lcm } ( M , N ) = M \times N$ with Chinese Remainder Thorem

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have seen people mentioning that this equation is a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem in some old posts, but I did not quite understand how. Can anyone elaborate on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please link a post where it referes to chinese remainder theorem..

Comment: It comes from the constructive proof of the theorem. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(direct_construction)) page.

Comment: Where do you see the gcd * lcm law there?  For ideals in a domain it is equivalent to one form of CRT, see $(27)$ and $(14)$ in [these characterizations of Prufer domains.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145267/242)

Comment: The use of Chinese Remainder Theorem is mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470807/prove-that-gcdm-n-times-mboxlcmm-n-m-times-n/470812

Comment: But no one seem to have elaborated on that.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205618/proving-that-mathbbz-m-oplus-mathbbz-n-cong-mathbbz-d-oplus-mathbbz

Comment: See also [this ancient question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122414/242)

Comment: Even though the answer by Lukas Heger in the link given by Ihf proves $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=m\cdot n$ by mentioning the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the CRT can be avoided. Namely, the answer proves the stronger result $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d\oplus \mathbb{Z}_l $ as groups, where  $l=\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$ and $d=\gcd(m,n)$. The proof uses the CRT and the identity $\operatorname{max}(m,n)+\operatorname{min}(m,n)=m+n$. Now, if you are only interested in proving $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=m\cdot n$, …

Comment: … you only need the identity $\operatorname{max}(m,n)+\operatorname{min}(m,n)=m+n$. Employing the CRT is an unnecessary detour.